# Why supplying a pointer argument to %s does not work?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, format-specifiers

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "header.h"


void main() {
int input;

FILE* of = NULL;
FILE* rf = NULL;
char* ptr = NULL;
while (1) {
    printf("1.writeFile\n2.ReadFile\n3.removeFile\n4.exit\n>>");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    switch (input) {
    case 1:
        makeFile(of, ptr);
        break;
    case 2:
        readFile(rf);
        break;
    case 3:
        deleteFile();
        break;
    case 4:
        exit(1);
    }
  }

}

void makeFile(FILE* of, char* ptr) {

char name[10];
char str[50];
printf("Input file name >>");
scanf("%s", &name);
ptr = &name;

of = fopen(name, "w");

printf("FileName>> %s\n", *ptr);
printf("input text >>");
scanf("%s", str);
fputs(str, of);
}
```

When I wrote

```
(printf("FileName>> %s\n", *ptr);
```

I thought  it will work, because, I put in  address of `char name[50]` to pointer value, but, it dd not work.

So I change code to

```
printf("FileName>> %s\n", ptr);
```

and it works well, but I did not understand the logic.

Comment: Pointers are addresses. printf/scanf expects a valid memory address. So pass one to it, simple as that. Things like `scanf("%s", &name);` will not work, since it means "give the the address where the pointer itself is stored, then attempt to store a whole string there".

Comment: In addition to the answer, `ptr = &name;` just changes the value of the local parameter inside the `makeFile` function. It does *not* change the value of the `ptr` passed from `main`. And even if it did, the value of `&name` would no longer be valid when returning to `main`.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("FileName>> %s\n", ptr);` works because `printf` expects an argument of type `char *` for the `%s` specifier. Conversely, `*ptr` has the type `char` and thus cannot work in this case.

By the same logic, the `ptr = &name;` statement is faulty. In fact, `name` is already a pointer of type `char *`, pointing to the first element of `name[10]` array, while `&name`  has the type of `char **`

I think you should take some time to debug the code carefully, otherwise it will be hard to understand the effects of multiple errors interacting in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** -- `ptr` is a pointer, `*ptr` is not.

---

To elaborate, in your case,

```
printf("FileName>> %s\n", ptr);
```

works, because `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to a *string* as the argument. The type of `ptr` is `char *`. So, it is fine.

Referring `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1, *The fprintf function* (*emphasis mine*)

> `s`
>  If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a **pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type**.[...]

OTOH,

```
printf("FileName>> %s\n", *ptr);
```

won't work, because, `*ptr` will give you a `char` which is not the expected type of argument for `%s` format specifier. Using mismatched type of argument for any particular format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, you should change `void main()` to `int main(void)` atleast to conform to the standard.

Comment: umm.. %s needs type of pointer value(address, not memory) am i well understand??

Comment: @KIM I think you are right. You don't need to dereference the pointer.